# How to pull data using most recent status update per customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to construct a query that would only retrieve the most recent status update per customer.

I've attached an image of how the data is currently constructed and how I would like it to be returned.

[image]

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the database you are using. If it implements *tuples equality* you can do:

```
select *
from t
where (customer, status_time) in (
  select customer, max(status_time) from t group by customer
)
```

In PostgreSQL you could use the amazing `DISTINCT ON`. Worst case scenario, you'll need to use a correlated subquery; it's slower but can do the job.

**Edit for SQL Server**

In SQL Server you can use a CTE to precompute the max status time. For example you can do:

```
with
a as (
  select customer, max(status_time) as max_time
  from t 
  group by customer
)
select
from t
join a on a.customer = t.customer 
      and a.max_time = t.status_time
```

Comment: Not well versed in Tech talk, however the database I believe is: MS SQL Server Management Studio